# Why does my CSS layout keeps breaking when i resize my screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

Every time I practice `CSS` layouts, each time I resize the browser window, the screen on the right side of the site keeps getting cut off, so there will be an empty space with a white background. Can someone help me identify the issue so I can permanently avoid this from happening again? Here is the `HTML` code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}

header {
  background: url(http://www.moirmedia.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Backgroundlow.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
  background-position: inherit;
  height: 165vh;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 5rem;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-text h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hero-text p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h2 class="logo">Logo</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Banner Text Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum <br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum <br> Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your css code from this

```
nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  right: 5rem;
  padding: 0 4rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

to changed one

```
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `padding` and `right` styles you have set on `nav ul li` push the content outside of the parent container. Adding in some responsive breakpoints with [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) will fix your issue and give you greater control of your layout at different screen resolutions. MDN has an article [Beginner's guide to media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries) providing more information on media queries.

Below is an example of using media queries with your code. Note how each breakpoint has specified a `padding-right` value which you may need to tweak so that your content fits as expected. Fine tuning can be a process. I used breakpoints from [Typical Device Breakpoints](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_media_query_breakpoints.asp) as a good starting point.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}

header {
  background: url(http://www.moirmedia.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Backgroundlow.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
  background-position: inherit;
  height: 165vh;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

nav h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.hero-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-text h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hero-text p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: justify;
}

/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  nav ul li {
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
  }
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  nav ul li {
    padding-right: 0.8rem;
  }
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  nav ul li {
    padding-right: 1.8rem;
  }
}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  nav ul li {
    padding-right: 3rem;
  }
}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  nav ul li {
    right: 5rem;
    padding-right: 4rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h2 class="logo">Logo</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Banner Text Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum <br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum <br> Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here is an alternative approach using [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) properties such as `justify-content` and putting the padding on `a` elements to increase touch target size which improves accessibility of your site. I'd suggest this option as it's less code to manage, a more modern approach, and achieves similar results.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
}

header {
  background: url(http://www.moirmedia.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Backgroundlow.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
  background-position: inherit;
  height: 165vh;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background: black;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

nav h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.hero-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.hero-text h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.hero-text p {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  text-align: justify;
}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  nav ul {
    justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    padding: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h2 class="logo">Logo</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1>Banner Text Heading</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum <br> Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum <br> Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</header>
```

Either option still doesn't fit all of your `nav` items on a single line on small screen such as mobile devices. I suggest you look into alternative [navigation patterns](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/05/basic-patterns-mobile-navigation/) such as a collapsible menu or even just wrap your content with `flex-wrap: wrap;` as [@Yudiz_Webdesign noted in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59639530/1494989).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll be learning Media Queries next for sure.